Add QC matrices to the seurat object while working with scRNAseq data
I am trying to analysis scRNAseq data and have both matrix and h5 as input for my pipeline (I have tried both off them). I have used the same pipeline before and worked perfectly.
the following lines are the beginning of the pipeline till I add information about the mitochondrial genes to the seurat object.
data <- Read10X_h5(filename = 'test_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5')

counts <-  data$`Gene Expression`

data <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = counts, project = "test", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)

data[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(data, pattern = "^MT-")

after running the last line of the pipeline, I get the following error. do you know how solve the error?
I get the same error if I use matrix files as input. here is the last few lines of the error:
"ZFY-AS1", "LINC00278", "PCDH11Y", "PRKY", "USP9Y", "AC244213.1", "DDX3Y", "UTY", "TMSB4Y", "NLGN4Y", "NLGN4Y-AS1",   "TTTY14", "AC010889.1", "KDM5D", "AC010889.2", "TTTY10", "EIF1AY", "MT-ND1", "MT-ND2", "MT-CO1", "MT-CO2",   "MT-ATP8", "MT-ATP6", "MT-CO3", "MT-ND3", "MT-ND4L", "MT-ND4", "MT-ND5", "MT-ND6", "MT-CYB", "MAFIP", "AC011043.1",   "AL354822.1", "AL592183.1", "AC240274.1", or "AC007325.4", not "counts". ℹ Did you mean "CLINT1"?

---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─Seurat::PercentageFeatureSet(nsclc.seurat.obj, pattern = "^MT-")
  2. │ ├─features %||% ...
  3. │ ├─base::grep(...)
  4. │ │ └─base::is.factor(x)
  5. │ ├─base::rownames(x = object[[assay]][layer])
  6. │ ├─object[[assay]][layer]
  7. │ └─SeuratObject:::`[.Assay`(object[[assay]], layer)
  8. │   ├─SeuratObject::LayerData(...)
  9. │   └─SeuratObject:::LayerData.Assay(features = i)
 10. │     └─rlang::arg_match(...)
 11. │       └─rlang:::arg_match_multi(arg, values, error_arg, error_call)
 12. │         └─rlang:::map_chr(arg, ~arg_match0(.x, values, error_arg, error_call = error_call))
 13. │           └─rlang:::.rlang_purrr_map_mold(.x, .f, character(1), ...)
 14. │             └─base::vapply(.x, .f, .mold, ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE)
 15. │               └─rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 16. │                 └─rlang::arg_match0(.x, values, error_arg, error_call = error_call)
 17. └─rlang:::stop_arg_match(w, values = x, error_arg = y, error_call = z)
 18.   └─rlang::abort(msg, call = error_call, arg = error_arg)


Have you tried to explicitly specify the assay and slot in the PercentageFeatureSet function to ensure it looks in the correct place? :
seurat_obj[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(seurat_obj, pattern = "^MT-", assay = "RNA", slot = "counts")
